# Stop Visual Studio 2010 opening XSDs in design mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd

Visual Studio 2010 now opens XSD files in design mode by default. I can't find any option for disabling this. Is there a way to always open XSD files in text mode?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Right click on an XSD file, choose "Open with..." and select the appropriate option - then click on "Set as Default" before you actually open it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. XSD files are still opened with the same application (VS2010) in "Design" mode. How can you prevent VS from opening in Design mode and just go straight to the text?..

Comment: @Peter: It does answer the question - if you pick the right option (e.g. "XML (Text) editor" *and set it as the default* then it will use that next time you double-click on the file in Solution Explorer. I've just tried it myself.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the answer and assumed the 'right-click' was to be done in windows explorer. You're right, this does work from within visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012, right click XSD file, Advanced, View with.