# XSD file fails to open in table design mode in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, xsd, visual-studio-2017, tableadapter

Some XSD files are opened immediately in Design view (see image below). While others in the same solution are opened in the table design view (where I see the table adapters visually).

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099304/stop-visual-studio-2010-opening-xsds-in-design-mode), but when I try to open it with the XML Schema Designer I still get the design view. How can I open the xsd file to actually see the table adapters again?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click the file.xsd, choose Open With... and choose Dataset Editor

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had to fiddle a little with opening the different files of the problematic dataset: `.xsd`, `.designer.vb`, clicking 'View Code' and `View Designer` and all of a sudden it opened again normally. I also restarted Visual Studio once or twice. Extremely strange, but it did the trick for me.

Comment: This also worked for the same problem in Visual Studio 2015.